# AWS hosted data storage for storing simple entities

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I need to choose data storage for simple system. The main purpose of the system is storing events - simple entities with timestamp, user id and type. No joins. Just single table.

Stored data will be fetched rarely (compared with writes). I expect following read operations:

- get latest events for a list of users
- get latest events of a type for a list of users

I expect about 0.5-1 million writes a day. Data older than 2 years can be removed.

I'm looking for best fitted service provided by AWS. I wonder if using redshift is like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Comment: go for rds-postgres (or mysql if you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can use AWS DynamoDB and also define the TTL values to remove the older items automatically. You get the following advantages.

- Fully managed data storage
- Able to scale with the need for write throughput (Though it can be costly)
- Use sort key with timestamp to query latest items.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to check the AWS Simple DB as it looks more fit(in a first glance) for your requirements.

Please refer this article which explains some practical user experience.

http://www.masonzhang.com/2013/06/2-reasons-why-we-select-simpledb.html